# using jquery.form.wizard-3.0.4.min.js inside a SharePoint 2010 Application page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, sharepoint-2010

has anyone seen any issues with using a form wizard inside a nested form tag?  i am using jquery.form.wizard-3.0.4.js

the problem is that i have to jam the form-wizard into a SharePoint Application page and sharepoints masterpage has a form tag in it and inside there if the ContentPlaceHolder.  In my aspx page i have the form-wizard Form tag

nothing happens when executed.  I think something happens that it is only looking at the top level form tag and that is it, not adding any classes etc.

any solutions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with nested form tags.  SharePoints MastePage has a form tag and then I have a form tag within my SharePoint Application Page for the form-wizard.  I removed the use of the MasterPage and all works fine.

i also tested this outside of SharePoint to make sure it was the issue and it happens in a simple aspx page.

Hope this helps others.